# Align Boxplot and Barplot in R

Tags: r, boxplot, bar-chart

I am very new to R. For my studies i need to plot the number of animals I found during 16 transects into a boxplot and a barplot. I want to combine both plots to one image using mfrow. The x axis shows dates i was in the field doing transects with several stops. the boxplot shows the variability between the stops. the barplot show the overall activity during the specific date of the 3 taxa.
The plots are fine but i am not able to align them so that the boxplot of date One is below the barplot of the same date.
I used the "at" parameter of the boxplots to align them as i wanted, but i am not able to align the barplot to the settings i used at the boxplot as it does not use "at", but "width" and "space".

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))

barplot(t(test), width=0.8,col=c("darkgoldenrod1","black","antiquewhite"),ylim=c(0,250),xlim=c(0.5,18),space=c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,1.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,1.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3))

boxplot(x~y,xlim=c(1,18),at =c(1,2,3,4, 6,7,8,9, 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18),outcex=1)
```

Is there any way to get these two plots together so that the fit to eachother?

EDIT:
i played a little with the width, xlim and space but there must be a better way then that

EDIT2:
This is the current plot i created
[image]

Comment: 14 values are 0.2 and the other 2 values are 1.4. For once, a table would do fine for these data.

Comment: @NickCox That's not the data, it's the spacing between bars. OP doesn't show the data (i.e., `test`). Right now the question seems to be only about programming and would fit better on Stack Overflow if a reproducible example was provided.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for that correction; I didn't look carefully enough and in any case R is not my daily software. I voted to close earlier.

Comment: The stacked bars show counts of three taxa, it seems. How do you get several numbers for the box plots?

Comment: I should have specified it a bit more. The x axis shows dates i was in the field doing transects with several stops. the boxplot shows the variability between the stops. the barplot show the overall activity during the specific date of the 3 taxa

Comment: No ideas for that task?